# Usage of minipage in a single column of a two column document

Tags: minipage, two-column

I want to insert two figures side by side in one column, in a two column document, using minipage.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]  

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]     
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

I can't understand why this doesn't work. Is this by design (of minipage)?
If so, what alternative do I have?

I [searched](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column+minipage) relevant topics without success.

Comment: .4\textwidth is almost the full width of the column,  you want .4\columnwidth   but if you have no captions you do not need minipage at all, simply use two `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thanks, David, that was indeed obvious but... couldn't figure that out! Anyway, the real  document has different things in the two columns (figures, text, so I'll stick with minipage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\columnwidth`, rather than `\textwidth` (which gives the width of the full page, not the column):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]  

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}

\lipsum[1]     
\end{document}
```

(Note each image is slightly less than half the column width, to allow for space between, etc.) Notice also that the `\textwidth` specified in `\includegraphics` is *within* the minipage environment, and as such returns the width of the minipage.

In fact, for this example you don't need to use `minipage` at all:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]  

\noindent
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\columnwidth]{example-image-a}

\lipsum[1]     
\end{document}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: Two columns with images side-by-side in one column]

Comment: Thanks, that so was obvious!

Comment: About your edit: Yes, true that minipage is not needed when only two figures. But the real document has in fact a mix of text and a figure, so I'll stick with minipage. Thanks again.

Comment: @kebs yes, I did wonder whether that was a requirement (which had been lost in the MWE), hence I gave both. (I'm not a fan of SE users who say "you shouldn't do it that way, do it this way". They tend to be the same users who also insist on really minimal MWEs...)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

***If You want to use `minipage` You can take this:***

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]  

\noindent


\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.49\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{}
\label{ris:image1}

\end{figure}


\lipsum[1]     
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but my answer answers the question specifically, without unnecessary manipulation (as I think).